# C++ generic type implementation with self defined class

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and work on an exercis. I have the following C++ code:

```
template <typename T, int length>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(T values[length])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            list[i] = values[i];
        }
        friend bool operator<(const Vector<T, length>& left,
            const Vector<T, length>& right)
        {
            bool result = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            result &= left.list[i] < right.list[i];
            return result;
        }
    private:
    T list[length];
    };


    int main()
    {
        int first[] = {1, 2}, second[] = {2, 3}; 
        Vector<int, 2> vector1(first), vector2(second);
        cout << (vector1 < vector2) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I have a class Int:

```
class Int
{
public:
    Int(int i = 0) {this->i = i;}
private:
    int i;
};
```

I tried to implement this class in the main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    Int first[] = {Int(1), Int(2)}, second[] = {Int(2), Int(3)}; 
    Vector<Int, 2> vector1(first), vector2(second);
    cout << (vector1 < vector2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile. I guess there is something wrong in the class Int. Could anyone give some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `It does not compile` Why not? What's the error? Compilers give you an error message for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your implementation of `operator<` in the template `Vector` uses `<` in the type `T`. If you instantiate `Vector` with `int` it is not a problem, since `int` comparison is builtin. But if you instantiate `Vector` with your `Int` class, which does not define `<` the compiler has no idea what to do in the line

```
result &= left.list[i] < right.list[i];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error is like this: binary '<': 'const Int' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator. It seems there's something wrong with the overloaded operator "<" in the Vector class

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree that the problem is the operator "<". How do I fix this problem.

Comment: You need to implement `operator<` in `Int` similarly to what you did in `Vector`, but obviously its body will be much simpler.

Comment: I tried to add the following code but it still does not work. Could you please show me how to do it? I really appreciate your help.         bool operator< (const Int& a){return i < a.i;}

Comment: You are nearly there. The operator in the comment above is for comparison between `Int&` and `const Int&`. Add `const`: `bool operator<(const Int& a) const {return i < a.i;}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can use *this in a constructor, since it still hasnt made the object. a more proper way to do it would be this:

```
class Int {
    public:
        Int(int i = 0) I(i) {}
    private:
        int I;
};
```

edit: It would also be helpful if you could post the errors as we dont know whats wrong with it

Comment: You can use this in a constructor body. If you do not call the members' constructor explicitly the default is called for you. Also, you are missing a : before the `I(i)`.

Comment: thank you, and my bad. i was kind of rushed writing that